# php with Curl: follow redirect with POST

Tags: php, redirect, post, curl

I have a script that send POST data to several pages. however, I encountered some difficulties sending request to some servers. The reason is redirection. Here's the model:

1. I'am sending post request to server
2. Server responses: 301 Moved Permanently
3. Then curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE) kicks in and follows the redirection (but via GET request).

To solve this I'am using curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST") and yes, now its redirecting without POST body content that I've send in first request. How can I force curl *to send post body when redirected*? Thanks!

Here's the example:

```
<?php 
function curlPost($url, $postData = "")
{
    $ch = curl_init () or exit ( "curl error: Can't init curl" );
    $url = trim ( $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    //curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec ( $ch );
    if (! $response) {
        echo "Curl errno: " . curl_errno ( $ch ) . " (" . $url . " postdata = $postData )\n";
        echo "Curl error: " . curl_error ( $ch ) . " (" . $url . " postdata = $postData )\n";
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        echo "HTTP code: ".$info["http_code"]."\n";
        // exit();
    }
    curl_close ( $ch );
    // echo $response;
    return $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: put your php code in post with example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

curl is following what [RFC 7231 suggests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2), which also is what browsers typically do for 301 responses:

```
  Note: For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
  method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.  If this
  behavior is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code
  can be used instead.
```

If you think that's undesirable, you can change it with the `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` option, which only seems very sparsely documented in PHP but [the libcurl docs explains it](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.html). By setting the correct bitmask there, you then make curl *not* change method when it follows the redirect.

If you control the server end for this, an easier fix would be to make sure a 307 response code is returned instead of a 301.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Didn't find anything on the net about this. Also, php says: "Notice: Use of undefined constant CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL" so there is no this constant defind and I just used curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3). It works nice now. Thanks again, your pretty good!